# Error: The 'Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010

is there anything wrong with my code?
i want to add, update and delete in a database using vb13

here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Private Sub cmdexit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdexit.Click
    Close()

End Sub

Private Sub cmdclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdclear.Click
    txtaddress.Text = ""
    txtstdntid.Text = ""
    txtstdntname.Text = ""
    txttelephone.Text = ""
    txtstdntid.Tag = ""

    cmdedit.Enabled = True

    cmdadd.Text = "Add"

    txtstdntid.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub RefreshData()

    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT stdid as [ID], " & "stdname as [Name], Gender, Phone, Address " & "FROM student ORDER BY stdid", cnn)

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    cnn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub cmdadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdadd.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn

    If txtstdntid.Tag & "" = "" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student(stdid, stdname, gender, phone, address) " & "VALUES(" & txtstdntid.Text & ",'" & txtstdntname.Text & "','" & Cmbgender.Text & "','" & txttelephone.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE student" & "SET stdid=" & txtstdntid.Text & ", stdname='" & txtstdntname.Text & "'" & ", gender='" & Cmbgender.Text & "'" & ", phone='" & txttelephone.Text & "'" & "WHERE stdid=" & txtstdntid.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    RefreshData()

    cmdclear.PerformClick()

    cnn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Mircosoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\data.mdb"

    RefreshData()

End Sub

Private Sub cmdedit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdedit.Click
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intStdID As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("id").Value
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM student " & "WHERE stdid=" & intStdID, cnn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            txtstdntid.Text = intStdID
            txtstdntname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("stdname")
            Cmbgender.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("gender")
            txttelephone.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("phone")
            txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("address")

            txtstdntid.Tag = intStdID

            cmdadd.Text = "Update"

            cmdedit.Enabled = False

            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmddelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmddelete.Click
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intStdID As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("id").Value
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If

            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM student WHERE stdid=" & intStdID
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            RefreshData()

            cnn.Close()

        End If
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `da.Fill(dt)` will take care of opening the connection if it needs to. It will leave the .ConnectionState the same as it was before it was called. You really should not be leaving a connection in an open state ;)

Comment: Just google the error message for a *ton* of hits that tell you about this problem.  You *do* have to spell it correctly, the company is called "Microsoft".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is already provided by many other web sites.

Answer (score 1):

That error is usually a result of your app running in a 64-bit process while the Jet OLE DB provider only exists as a 32-bit library.  If you want to use Jet on a 64-bit machine then you must ensure that your app runs in a 32-bit process.  You do that by setting the Target Platform in the project properties to x86 or, if available, leave it set to the default Any CPU and check the Prefer 32-bit box.  Your app will then run in a 32-bit process on all machines, whether the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit.